# Need same design for different types of devices in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, layout

I created a button layout design as shown in the picture. How can i implement the pattern of design for different size of screens? This layout is fit for 3.7 inch screen but not in others. May be scrollview is an option, but that is not satisfy me. How can i do it? Any help?

[image]

This is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can you weight instead of relative layout.. If you use relative layout concept it will fit all screen.
Try out the below xml and check in different screen.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="8" >

     <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="Button" />

  <Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="Button" />

  <Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="Button" />

   <Button
android:id="@+id/button4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="Button"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

The weight sum in Linear layout will take the whole screen size. And the layout_weight will fix the button according to the weights..

Comment: its not even displays the button :-(